# Cannot boot ubuntu 22.04 - can I recover OS from Grub minimal? Or get to home files to delete them?

Tags: boot, grubrescue

Hello everyone and thanks so much for your previous help. I still can't boot and I can't use a flash drive because I get 2 errors, an error 71 along with a home file that is too full. These are my errors:

```
[ 0.459335 pc1 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PI0 log size 0 is invalid
[ 0.471579] pc1 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PI0 log size 0 is invalid
/dev/nvme0n1p2 : clean, 428341/31227904 files, 118762740/124895488 blocks
```

I can get to Minimal Grub commands. Can I recover my Ubuntu OS from here? If not, can I get to my home file so I can delete files and hopefully get to a graphical screen?

Comment: What flash drive is it? How did you prepare it: from which Ubuntu iso file? With which tool? Does it boot in some other computer?

Comment: DPC Looks like bug report filed. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209943 The clean is a comment saying file system does not need fsck.  You should be able to boot a live installer or is this error from a full install to a flash drive?  Have you updated UEFI firmware? And if SSD its firmware?

Comment: The usual method is to boot a LiveUSB installer instead of your HDD, select the "Try Ubuntu" environment, then mount your HDD and external drives, then you can do your file actions safely. Minimal Grub won't get you there.

Comment: To answer questions - I can't use a usb flash drive because of error 71. The usb drive is the one I originally installed 22.04 with which was made with Rufus. I also have a 20.04 - neither work due to the error 71.

Comment: Yes, the error is from my Dell xps 13 SSD hard drive. It does not see my usb live drives, not windows 10, or ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04. Can I update the UEFI or SSD firmware from Minimal Grub - because that is as far as I can get. Please help - newbie here. But I was able to find what partition ubuntu is on...that's a start.

Comment: Yes! It does look like that bug - going to see if that helps or if they have a workaround.

Comment: No luck - but this looks more serious than I thought. Any ideas on how to move forward? Maybe replace the hard drive?

Comment: @Linparda, To replace the hard disk drive might help, but only if the hard disk drive is causing the problem. There might be another cause of the problem. (I don't know what error 71 means.) - Anyway, as a start, **please remove the hard disk drive, and then try to boot from the USB drive**. If it is still good (you can test it in another computer), your computer should boot from it, if the hard disk drive was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dell XPS 13 9310 -

From Paul Menzel: (In reply to Paul Menzel from comment #28)
@linparda, your problem is very likely unrelated. (In the GRUB menu, press the key e and remove quiet from the Linux kernel command line. Then boot with F10 or Ctrl + x.) It’s a problem you should report to Ubuntu though.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209943#c28

I switched out the Dell A to C usb adapter and was finally able to see the flash drive to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04.
Thank you everyone! Hope this helps.